# Submit 3 HTML forms with one Javascript button to store in same MySQL DB row

Tags: html, forms

I have a page with 3 forms without submit button. Then I created a script to submit all at the same time to the same file however it creates 3 rows in database but I need all together in same row. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
            submitForms = function(){
            document.getElementById("form1").submit();
            document.getElementById("form2").submit();
            document.getElementById("form3").submit();
            }
        </script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="submitForms()">Click me!</button>
    <form id="form1" action="test.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="A" value="A"/>
       </form>
    <form id="form2" action="test.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="B" value="B"/>
       </form>
    <form id="form3" action="test.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="C" value="C"/>
       </form>
```

```html
 elseif(isset($_POST)) {
            $A = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['A']);
            $B = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['B']);
            $C = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['C']);
            mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO something (A, B, C) VALUES ('$A', '$B', '$C')");
            header('Location: ../Index.php');
            exit();
```

Comment: Why do you need three forms? Just use one form with three inputs

Comment: I don't get why you shouldn't use one form only for the three inputs togheter. You don't have any option to post each one singularly, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then put it all in one form (which is basically what in 99.999% of cases would be needed):

```
<button type="submit" onclick="submitForms()">Click me!</button>
<form id="form1" action="test.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="A" value="A"/>
   <input type="text" name="B" value="B"/>
   <input type="text" name="C" value="C"/>
</form>
```

Edit:
A form can span many tags, not necessarily only `<input>` tags (or `<select>`, etc). So this is perfectly valid too:

```
<form id="form1" action="test.php" method="post">
    <div class="class1">
        <div class="class2">
            <input type="text" name="A" value="A"/>
        </div>
        <div class="class2">
            <input type="text" name="B" value="B"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="class3">
        <input type="text" name="C" value="C"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I do need 3 separate forms. They are separate in different <div> containers. My case is on the 00.01% :)

Comment: And why, if I may ask?

Comment: because that's the way I want it to be

Comment: Jordi Nebot, do you mean <div><form><input bla bla><div><input bla bla></div></form></div> ?

Comment: Thank you Peter B and Jordi Nebot. That is a clever solution that I didn't think about but will definetly solve my case and also I can get rid of JavaScript code :)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tries unfortunately is extremely hard to put all together within the order that I wish. This page contains many things so if someone else is able to provide a solution that is not using the same form with different div container I appreciate. Thanks

Comment: I am thinking if I have inputs outside the form but in each input use form="myform". Can it be a solution?

Comment: It works but I am also using a select but it doesn't work with select. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is actually working with select too. I just wrote the id incorrectly. Thanks for everything!